# Why does this if statement result in "TypeError: string indices must be integers"?

Tags: python

I'm trying to cut things from my string (`mirror`) but I'm stuck with following problem.

I tried to put the part of the string that I am pointing on inside `int()`.

```
for i in mirror:
    if mirror[i] == '\\':
        mirror = mirror[i:i+2]
```

Comment: Think about what `for i in miror` does

Comment: then you should not modify a list you're looping on

Comment: @PRMoureu `miror` is a `string`, as stated by OP

Comment: What are you trying to do with your string?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to remove character(s) from a string, might I suggest `replace()` rather than iterating over the string:

```
>>> a = 'abc//123'
>>> a.replace('//', '')
abc123
>>> b = a.replace('//', '')
>>> a
abc//123
>>> b
abc123
```

You are getting a `TypeError` because `i` is a `str`, not an `int`. Observe the line `for i in mirror` - *`mirror` is a `str`, so each character `i` in `mirror` is also a `str`.* You are then trying to index your string with a `str`, which is invalid, resulting in a `TypeError`.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are iterable, so when you type this:

```
for i in "string":
    print i
```

You'll get this

```
s
t
r
i
n
g
```

If you want to get the indexes of the string use `enumerate`

```
for i, c in enumerate("string"):
    print i,c
```

results in:

```
0 s
1 t
2 r
3 i
4 n
5 g
```